# win32.GetWindowText doesnt return any text

Tags: python

I want the program to print every window handle and its corresponding title. I do get the handles but i dont get any name.

OUTPUT:

```
1968350 ""

197206 ""

131300 ""

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 13, in <module>
722502     main()
  
File "C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 5, in main
    list_window_names()
 
File "C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 11, in list_window_names
    win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)
  
File "C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 10, in winEnumHandler
    print(hwnd, '"' + win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) + '"')
  
File "C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25cf' in position 1: character maps to >undefined>
```

Code:

```
import win32gui


def main():
        list_window_names()

def list_window_names():
    def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
        if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
            print(hwnd, '"' + win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) + '"')
    win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)

main()
```

Comment: error shows problem with char `\u25cf'` and `encodings\cp1252.py` - problem is that console in Windows uses encoding `CP1252` instead of `utf-8` and code has problem to display char with code `\u25cf'`. You may have to remove this char from string or you have to change settings in registers so console will use `UTF-8`. Probably in Windows this encoding has name `65001` (or something similar) and you can find many answers how to change it. You saw it on Stackoverflow or on similar portal [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: [Why is there no option to choose codepage 65001 (UTF-8) as a default codepage in console window? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/692202/why-is-there-no-option-to-choose-codepage-65001-utf-8-as-a-default-codepage-in)

Comment: BTW: on Linux char `\u25cf` is displayed as `●`

Comment: Thank you i just removed the character from the  string and it worked!